# Pytorch testing/validation accuracy over 100%

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, pytorch, accuracy

So I was training my CNN for some hours when it reached 99% accuracy (which was a little bit too good, I thought). But then it didn´t stop and it went higher than 100%. So I thought, that must be because I messed something up in the accuracy calculater function, but I didnt find the mistake. Can somebody tell me if something is wrong here?

```
def accuracy(model, dataset):
    # set .eval() to ignore dropout
    model = model.eval()
    accuracy = 0
    total = 0
    correct = 0
    for _, data in enumerate(dataset):
        samples, targets = data
        samples = samples.float().cuda()
        targets = targets.float().cuda()

        predictions = model(samples)

        total += targets.size(0)
        correct += predictions.eq(targets.data).sum().item()

    accuracy = 100 * correct/total
    return accuracy
```

Arguments: the model, and the dataset (for example the validation set or the testing set)
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why is there a zero in `targets.size(0)`?

Comment: thats the batch size

Comment: I found the error:
predictions.eq(targets.data) compares the two tensors, and if there are equal values it fills a new tensor of the same shape with a True.
The .sum() counts the Trues. But because my targets look like this [1/0, 1/0, 1/0], there can be multiple matches per target so ie if the target was [1, 0, 0] and I got [1, 0 ,0 ] .sum() will return 3 Trues, but I want 1 True.